# Sum values with same name

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have an ODS file with a long list of names and amounts in columns A and B. Many of the names are duplicates. For example

```
John  | 10
Bill  | 2
Susan | 3
Frank | 4
Sally | 10
John  | 2
Susan | 2
John  | 3
```

Is there any automated way to combine all of the values so I get another list of names and amounts in columns C and D, without any duplicate names and a single sum of all of each person's entry? For example

```
John  | 15
Bill  | 2
Susan | 5
Sally | 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly what a pivot table does.  Add labels in the first row, then go to *Data -> Pivot Table -> Create*.  Drag "Name" to Row Fields, and "Amount" to Data Fields.

For complete instructions, see https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/133298/how-can-i-calculate-aggregate-sums-in-calc/#133325.